# Reading form data from a multi part request

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl, kotlin, jvm

I have a curl command which is posting data using multiform/form-data as Content Type. request is as follows

curl -X POST http://localhost:50005/77    -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'    -F 'instruction={   "action": "produce",   "data": [     {       "id": "user1",       "type": "Person"}   ] }'

How do I read the "instruction" parameter from the request in my spring boot controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Curl request was not correct, the correct curl request is 
curl -X POST http://localhost:50005/77 -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' -F instruction='{ "action": "produce", "data": [ { "id": "user1", "type": "Person"} ] }'